# EJS multiple templates in one file

Tags: javascript, templates, web-applications, backbone.js, ejs

I am playing around with EJS and Backbone and I was wondering:
Is there a way to have multiple templates in just one .ejs file? I have a set of different views I always need to render, but wasting multiple GET requests doesnt seem to be really smart. I couldnt really find anything in the documentation or google though. I know there are partials, but since I render on the client side, that doesnt really help.

Or is there another client side templating library that could do this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an ejs template is basically a string, so just set each template to a different variable. and put them all in one .js file.

```
//templates.js
var templates = (function(){
  this.titleTemplate = "<h1> <%= title %> </h1>";
  this.otherTemplate = "<h1> <%= otherTitle %> </h1>";
  return this;
})()
```

than you can access the templates in your other code like this:

```
templates.titleTemplate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper that concatenates your files. It's good to have one file for each template, so you can align your code nicely etc.

Check out Jammit: http://mikeferrier.com/2011/04/29/blogging-with-jekyll-haml-sass-and-jammit/